# Disable Cash on delivery in citrus payment gatway for specific product in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, citrus

I am using citrus payment in magento website its working good but there is an option in admin in citrus payment method i.e. Show COD option and i disable it but COD option is still enable after placing order using citrus payment in frontend.

Comment: you want to hide COD for specific product right ? than why you are using citrus ?

Comment: I want to hide cod option in citrus payment method when user select this payment option for using payment through net backing,debit,credit card,cod. citrus use flag for this named "check for incoming flags" available in citrus account.basically if "show cod option" is set to "N" from magento admin panel then Cod should be disable from citrus but it is not working.

Comment: git it, Thanks i didt understood correctly. below answers also will not help for you. hope citrus team will help you for this soon.

Comment: yes i have reported them for this issue

Answer (score 1):

To disable "**Cash On Delivery**" on frontend, simply go to 
app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\Cashondelivery.php
and paste following code:

```
protected $_canUseCheckout              = false; 
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = false;
```

Comment: i did not want to disable on FRONTEND. i want to disable it when it is redirecting to citrus payment link after place order continue button clicked

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to choose correct store to edit.

After disable COD from payment methods and clear cache.

If it is not working you can use css by:

```
display:none;
```